# Dapper QueryAsync Message return task canceled

Tags: c#, asynchronous, dapper

I am having a error with dapper and async method. What am I doing wrong?

This is my code.

```
public Task<IEnumerable<Student>> GetStudentsAsync(int type)
{
    var sql = "[dbo].[StudentController_GetStudents]";

    var students = Connection.QueryAsync<Student>(sql,
        new
        {
            type
        },
        commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure
    );

    return students;
}

public Task<IEnumerable<Teacher>> GetTeachersAsync(int type)
{
    var sql = "[dbo].[StudentController_GetTeachers]";

    var teachers = Connection.QueryAsync<Teacher>(sql,
        new
        {
            type
        },
        commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure,
    );

    return teachers;
}


var studentsTask = StudentDao.GetStudentsAsync(type);

var teachersTask = StudentDao.GetTeachersAsync(type);


UpdateStudents(await studentsTask);

UpdateTeachers(await teachersTask);
```

I am having an error when I call "await teachersTask", the stack trace error is:

```
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.<QueryAsync>d__23`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong? I want to execute both queries same time, and then wait for the result.
I know is something with SQL connection is not open or something, but dont know how to fixed it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your error don't tell anything useful, can you check InnerException. And "await studentsTask" is working?

Comment: The inner exception is: {System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid attempt to read when no data is present. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.CheckDataIsReady(Int32 columnIndex, Boolea...

Comment: Yes the "await studenstasks" is working fine, but when executes "await teachersTask" throw an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this private method to open a connection with SQL, and use GetStudents to get the students and same goes for teachers.

```
    private SqlConnection GetConnection()
    {
        return new SqlConnection("ConnectionString");
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Student>> GetStudentsAsync(int type)
    {
        using (var connection = GetConnection())
        {  
            DynamicParameters param = new DynamicParameters();
                param.Add("@type", type);
            var result = await connection.QueryAsync<Student>("[dbo].[StudentController_GetStudents]",param, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            return result.ToList();
        }
    }

  public async Task<IEnumerable<Teacher>> GetTeachersAsync(int type)
    {
        using (var connection = GetConnection())
        {  
            DynamicParameters param = new DynamicParameters();
                param.Add("@type", type);
            var result = await connection.QueryAsync<Student>("[dbo].[StudentController_GetTeachers]",param, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            return result.ToList();
        }
    }

UpdateStudents(await StudentDao.GetStudentsAsync(type));

UpdateTeachers(await StudentDao.GetTeachersAsync(type));
```

Comment: It should work, because it is working in my application.
And don't forget to accept this is as a answer, after you try, and for the time being upvote.

Comment: One question...but would has sense to use async in my DAO if I have to wait for the result to execute the another method? Is that correct? I want to make then in paralell. Is that correct?

Comment: but would has sense to use async in my DAO if I have to wait for the result to execute the another method? Is that correct? Yes.  I want to make then in paralell. Is that correct? No

Comment: I would likie to make both methods in paralell, dont want to wait one query to start the another one, want to execute them in paralell and then just get the result with the await. How can I do that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177934/discussion-between-waqas-dilawar-daha-and-user2112420).